# Placing two elements - charts - under each other on the page

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I have a piece of D3.js code that draws a chart, and it width,height,etc.. are set like this:

```
<script>

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

And it draws fine on the page.
**To be exact: The script tag from this source:** https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/blob/master/examples/scatterplot/scatterplot.html

Then I copy-paste another piece of D3.js code that draws a bar chart and its width, height, etc... are set like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Width and height
    var w = 500;
    var h = 100;
    var barPadding = 1;
```

**To be exact: The script tag from this source code:** http://alignedleft.com/content/3.tutorials/10.d3/130.making-a-bar-chart/demo/10.html

How can I tell them not to overlap each other, I just simply want them for first one to show, then at the bottom of it the next one to show...

Comment: More context would help. Are you appending both charts into the same div or parent svg element?

Comment: @AndrewStaroscik : nop, they are two separate pieces of code inside their own script tags, I have taken them from web so one minute please, I can give you the direct link to both of them . Thanks for help.

Comment: @AndrewStaroscik : Updated the question with link to full source code of both charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create two separate svg elements and append them both to the body. See [this gist for a demonstration](http://bl.ocks.org/AndrewStaroscik/5232739). Notice each svg var has its own name (svgOne and svgTwo).

Comment: Thanks I will try it, but one question: I had copy pasted code from two different sources, each one was in itw own script blog, so when I put them in the code I had two separate script tags again, so still I need to change the SVG names although they are in different script blocks?

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, because I did it and it worked. But if you have some time please also answer the question I asked in the comment above.. Thanks Cuase now it looks like a mystery to me :)

Comment: I am not sure why it does not work.  I created another gist http://bl.ocks.org/andrewStaroscik/5232876 using the code you are interested in. The charts are stacking for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for your questions :

1. DIFFERENT SVG ELEMENTS : As pointed out by my friend above you can put in two different svg tags with different class name.

   ```
   var svg1 = d3.select(body)
                 .append(svg)
                 .attr('class', 'chart1')

   var svg2 = d3.select(body)
             .append(svg)
             .attr('class', 'chart2')
   ```

Then you can just use the variable

```
          svg1.append('rect').data().enter()
          svg2.append('rect').data().enter()
```

2. Using Grouping (G)  Tag: This allows you to group various charts in the svg but different G tags . You can think of them as Div tags for the Html.

You can see following post for d3:
[redraw function with g containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804295/redraw-function-with-g-containers)

Comment: Thanks, now I am posting another qestion regarding this code, in IE the charts show under each other, no new rows...in any other browsers then appear like in-line elements on the same row... I will update this comment with the new question too.

Comment: for your question above . I recommend keeping them in same script tag. And if you still keeping in the same block you have to keep in different variable names. The whole document will use common variable space till you load the web page again.

Comment: Every browser has its own style sheet of it renders a perticular tag which is there in the code . I am not sure of the problem you are speaking , but try searching for in google for CSS RESET SCRIPTS

Comment: Thanks, here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602028/charts-showing-on-the-same-line-in-non-ie-browsers-but-on-the-next-line-on-ie-b   
 You are more than welcome to post your thought as answer on that question, will try them. Thanks.