# Charts showing on the same line in non-IE browsers, but on the next line on IE browsers

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

Here is the exact code you can try for yourself:

http://bl.ocks.org/AndrewStaroscik/5232739

When I render this in IE, each chart shows in a different line.
When I render it in any other browser except for IE, charts show on the same line like in-line elements.

What is going on? What is the reason for this? Is there any fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me all are loading in the inline fashion the reason ? Because SVG has inline property associated by the USER AGENT of the browser . I am not sure which IE browser you used , but I am using IE 10.0 , chrome and firefox also the latest . EVERYTHING displays it INLINE .

ps: SVG doesn't work properly for IE less than 8

FIX : try reducing height and width of the svg using CSS . It might be pushed to next line for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, I have to test in IE 7 and IE 8 ... I was using IE 8 and because of that I also use R2D3 project, they use the same D3 if IE is 8+ , and use Raphael to Render it for IE 7 and 8 : https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/

Comment: But they have also mentioned that Raphel is inconsistent . It works in some and not in others . It is just a by-solution not a fix. You should make your user shift to IE 9 . Because IE 8 lacks rendering consistency

Answer (score 2):

Your charts render on two lines in all the browsers I tried (latest Chrome 26, latest Firefox 19, and IE 9).

They are contained in an `<iframe>` whose width is 960px. The width of each `<svg>` chart is 500px, so of course they can't display side-by-side without some kind of positioning of floating. Resize the charts or use CSS to cause them to overlap (or, if that's not the goal, then use CSS to force them to stack).

Comment: Thanks, Can you please show me an example of the CSS that I can use with them to make them overlap?

Comment: I agree with user113215.  One way to make sure they always stack is to put each of them into their own div

Comment: @BDotA What does "overlap" mean? To put both charts exactly on top of each other, you could use something like `position:absolute;top:0;left:0`. If you want both charts side-by-side, (which will cause part of the second chart to overflow off the right edge of the page and be invisible) put them both in a `<div>` with `width:1000px`.